# How to convert to and from DateTimeOffset and DateOnly?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a `DateTimeOffset` struct that i'd like to convert to and from `DateOnly`, but there seem to be no direct conversion options.

For `DateTime` there is `FromDateTime(DateTime dateTime)` - I do not see anything for `DateTimeOffset`.

How to convert to and from DateTimeOffset and DateOnly?

Comment: For DateOnly to DateTimeOffset could you use .ToDateTime? Then you could follow this to get to DateTimeOffset: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset

Answer (score 9):

You can just use `.Date` to get the date as a `DateTime` value, and `FromDateTime` to convert to `DateOnly`

```
DateOnly.FromDateTime(yourValue.Date)
```

Note that the result of this is the date before taking the offset into account.

Comment: This question is about `DateTimeOffset` not DateTime.

Comment: I never said it was about `DateTime`. There is a `Date` property on `DateTimeOffset`, which returns a `DateTime` value contaniing just the date

Comment: I really don't understand what your point is, please explain. The above code works when `yourValue` is a `DateTimeOffset` so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I'm re-reading this, I apologize you're right this does answer the "To DateOnly" half of the question, but not the 'ToDateTimeOffset" question.

Comment: Huh, I _had_ weird. Sorry!

Comment: I added an alternative answer because honestly no one should be doing any of this without considering the timezone or offset. *Perhaps* the DateTimeOffset => DateOnly conversion is safe, but the DateOnly => Offset is impossible without specifying precicely what time zone the date should count for.

Comment: This is what I was doing until I realised the offset could actually change the date. E.g. 3:00pm on the **1st** UTC would be 1:00am on the **2nd** UTC+10.

Answer (score 8):

These existing answers very helpful and definitely got me looking in the right direction. What is *missing* from them is handling time zones. You *may* not care if all your dates are always in the same zone as your server. The following methods cover that use case.

Play with the code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kFOTd3

```cs
public static class DateOnlyExtensions {
    public static DateTimeOffset ToDateTimeOffset(this DateOnly dateOnly, TimeZoneInfo zone) {
        var dateTime = dateOnly.ToDateTime(new TimeOnly(0));
        return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, zone.GetUtcOffset(dateTime));
    }

    public static DateOnly ToDateOnly(this DateTimeOffset dto, TimeZoneInfo zone) {
        var inTargetZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto, zone);

        return DateOnly.FromDateTime(inTargetZone.Date);
    }
}
```

These can be used as follows:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    var utc = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    var hawaii = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific/Honolulu");
    var christmasIslands = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific/Enderbury");

    Console.WriteLine("DateTimeOffset to DateOnly:");

    Console.WriteLine($"UTC Now: {now}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Date in Hawaii: {now.ToDateOnly(hawaii)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Date In Christmas Islands: now.ToDateOnly(christmasIslands)}");

    Console.WriteLine("====================\n");
    
    Console.WriteLine("DateOnly to DateTimeOffset");
    var totallyRandomDate = DateOnly.Parse("2020-03-11");
    Console.WriteLine($"DateTimeOffset UTC: {totallyRandomDate.ToDateTimeOffset(utc)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"DateTimeOffset Hawaii: {totallyRandomDate.ToDateTimeOffset(hawaii)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"DateTimeOffset Christmas Islands: {totallyRandomDate.ToDateTimeOffset(christmasIslands)}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just used constructors:

```
DateOnly do1 = new (2022,03,14);
DateTimeOffset dto1 = new(do1.Year, do1.Month, do1.Day, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
```

and

```
DateTimeOffset dto2 = new(2022,03,14,23,40,11, TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
DateOnly do2 = new (dto2.Year, dto2.Month, dto2.Day);
```